# Bundle item inside a bundle item

Tags: bundled-product

Is it possible  to put a bundle item inside another bundle item? 
i have 2 products, each with their own options.. lets call it product **A** and **B** but the two items are compatible, You can insert **A** into **B**, but as i said **A** has its own options.

is this possible in magento? or do i need an extension for it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with standard functionality. I have once seen such a thing for grouped products but they lost all upgrade ability. I do not know if there is any nice solution for that or if there is something already available.